# Golang: Break reading from socket without closing

Tags: sockets, networking, go, goroutine

I'm developing proxy server for a daemon that receives connects from Client(CC), then gets free connections to Server(SC) from pool of connections and starts two go routines, each one reads data from one connection and writes to another.

Here is my problem. When Client closes his connection, I catch it on read operation from CS and stop this routine. But I can't break reading process from the SC, so I can't bring this connection back to the pool.

Could you please recommend me some true pattern or something to fix this problem.

Comment: Some code would be useful.  Sounds like you need a `channel` to communicate between the two `go` routines.

Comment: Either close socket or use something in application protocol to indicate end of session.  For example, an HTTP proxy knows when to stop reading when it reaches end of response.

Comment: The only way to break a read from a connection is to close it, otherwise you'll need some other signaling, like polling for a close flag/chan, or something in the protocol itself.

Comment: Seems possible to set a read timeout from another coroutine and get the read to unblock with a timeout error.